# Android manifest Enable RTL flag for specific part of layouts

Tags: android, kotlin, migration, manifest, right-to-left

We have a big Android project with hundreds of layout files, and we currently are creating 2 layout files for every View (Fragment/Dialog...) one default and on RTL layout, which is a lot of effort to maintain and we are looking to enable `android:supportsRtl="true"` but its really hard to enable it and migrate/fix all layouts at once, and it will require a lot of work.

The question is: is it possible to enable this flag for some Layouts only and start working on this transition/migration slowly over time? or there is no way but to work on it all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While still requires some work, you can go over your layouts (xmls) and add:

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

or

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

To the root layout of each xml files.
This will force the direction for this specific layout.

Comment: Thank you, I was waiting for other answers that can make the work less and needs less testing afterwords but looks like there is not easy way in this situation, so I'll use your suggestion, or just refactor the whole thing